# FCM Notifications only sends on device when the application is not open and on background

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an application that has a function that whenever a data is added in the firebase realtime database it will send a notification on a group of device via FCM tokens. However it only sends notifications when the application is not opened and on background, but when the application is opened and running the notifications will not arrive.

I also tried it on notification "Send test message" and it still wont send notification if the application is currently open and running. Is this normal for FCM notifications? I have tried multiple devices and they are all the same, even on a emulator. So my questions is how do I enable the notification to send on the devices even when the application is currently running? I just want the standard notification above, and not the "In-App Messaging". Any explanation will help! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Messages are handled differently depending on the app state. You need a code implementation to handle the messages when the app is in foreground.

- [`onMessageReceived`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) for Android
- [`didReceiveRemoteNotification`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive#handle_silent_push_notifications) for iOS

> You can also check out these similar posts:
>
> - [How to handle the Firebase notification when app is in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38451582/20447561)
> - [Notification doesn't show when in foreground](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37609948/20447561)